# positive definite character

Tags: harmonic-analysis

‎‎We know each character on dual group of ‎$‎Z‎; ‎‎\widehat{Z}‎$‎‎, is positive definite and if‎ ‎$‎‎\chi‎‎ ‎\in‎ \widehat{Z}‎$ then ‎$‎‎\left\| ‎‎‎\chi‎‎ ‎\right\|‎_{‎\infty‎}‎‎=‎‎\chi(1)‎$‎. But I can not prove the problem that:‎

‎
Let  ‎$‎‎\chi‎‎  ‎\in‎\widehat{Z}‎$ and  ‎$(‎\chi‎_{n})‎\subset‎\widehat{Z}‎$.  Is when  ‎$‎‎\chi‎_{n}(1)\rightarrow ‎\chi(1)‎$‎, ‎then  ‎‎$‎‎‎\Vert‎‎‎\chi‎_{n}-\chi‎\Vert‎_{‎\infty‎}‎‎\rightarrow 0‎$‎ ?
‎